# Making columns in SQL lite for android devlopment

Tags: android, database, eclipse, sqlite

I am making a database using a data handler class that extends SQL Lite open helper. I copied a example but this example only had three columns ID, name and skill. I am wanting to add three more columns Strength, Loyalty and Weapon. The code works with the three columns but as soon as I add in three more it doesn't work and says it cannot find the new columns when creating the database. The code I am using is the following..

public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Cards.db";

private static final String TABLE_NAME = "card";

private static final String COL_ID = "id";

private static final String COL_NAME = "name";

private static final String COL_SKILL = "skill";

private static final String COL_STRENGTH = "strength";

private static final String COL_LOYALTY = "loyalty";

private static final String COL_WEAPON = "weapon";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
            + COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + COL_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + COL_SKILL + " TEXT" + 
            COL_STRENGTH + "TEXT" 
            + COL_LOYALTY + "TEXT" + COL_WEAPON + "TEXT"+
            ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
}


@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldNum, int newNum) {
    // Drop older table if exist and create fresh
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

public void addCard(Card card) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COL_ID, card.getID());
    values.put(COL_NAME, card.getName());
    values.put(COL_SKILL, card.getSkill());
    values.put(COL_STRENGTH, card.getStrength());
    values.put(COL_LOYALTY, card.getLoyalty());
    values.put(COL_WEAPON, card.getWeapon());
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    db.close();
}

public List<Card> getAll() {
    List<Card> list = new ArrayList<Card>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Card card = new Card(cursor.getInt(0),
                    cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2))
                    cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4),
                    cursor.getString(5)
                    );
            list.add(card);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return list;
}

public void removeAll() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

public void deleteCard(Card card) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_NAME, COL_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(card.getID()) });
    db.close();
}

public int updateCard(Card card) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COL_NAME, card.getName());
    values.put(COL_SKILL, card.getSkill());
    values.put(COL_STRENGTH, card.getStrength());
    values.put(COL_LOYALTY, card.getLoyalty());
    values.put(COL_WEAPON, card.getWeapon());
    return db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, COL_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(card.getID()) });
}

public Card getCard(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { COL_ID, COL_NAME,
            COL_SKILL, 
            COL_STRENGTH, COL_LOYALTY, COL_WEAPON 
            }, COL_ID + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    Card card = new Card(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
            cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2),
            cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4),
            cursor.getString(5)
            );
    return card;
}
```

}

I just can't figure out when it doesn't like the other columns I am trying to insert.

I also had a card class that looks like the following.

public class Card {

```
private int ID;

private String name;

private String skill;

private String strength; 

private String loyalty; 

private String weapon;


public Card(int ID, String name, String skill, String strength, String loyalty, String weapon) {
    this.ID = ID;
    this.name = name;
    this.strength = skill;
    this.skill = strength;
    this.loyalty = loyalty;
    this.weapon = weapon;
}

public String getName(){
    return this.name;
}

public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name;
}

public String getSkill(){
    return this.skill;
}

public void setSkill(String skill){
    this.skill = skill;
}

public String getStrength() {
    return this.strength;
}

public void setStrength(String strength) {
    this.strength = strength;
}

public String getLoyalty() {
    return this.loyalty;
}

public void setLoyalty(String loyalty) {
    this.loyalty = loyalty;
}

public String getWeapon() {
    return this.weapon;
}

public void setWeapon(String weapon) {
    this.weapon = weapon;
}

public int getID() {
    return ID;
}

public void setID(int iD) {
    ID = iD;
}
```

}

At the moment I am just testing the database works by writing it to the log in my browse class. The code I am using here is.

public class Browse extends Activity {

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout2);
    DatabaseHandler dh = new DatabaseHandler(this);

    Log.d("Database: ", "Dropping old table");
    dh.removeAll();

    Log.d("Database: ", "Inserting values..");
    dh.addCard(new Card(1, "Trevor", "11", "22", "33", "44"));
    dh.addCard(new Card(2, "Joseph", "49", "65", "87", "12"));
    dh.addCard(new Card(3, "Paul", "87", "12", "90", "01"));
    dh.addCard(new Card(4, "Mary", "30", "43", "12", "98"));

    Log.d("Database: ", "Listing all cards..");
    List<Card> list = dh.getAll();  
    for (Card lr : list) {
        String log = "ID:" + lr.getID() +" Name: " + lr.getName() + " Phone: " + lr.getSkill() + " Strength " + lr.getStrength()
                + " Loyalty: " + lr.getLoyalty() + " Weapon: " + lr.getWeapon();
        Log.d("Database: ", log); 
    }

    dh.deleteCard(new Card(1, "Trevor", "11", "22", "33", "44"));

    dh.updateCard(new Card(2, "Joseph", "36", "27", "87", "11"));

    Log.d("Database: ", "Re-listing all cards..");
    list = dh.getAll();
    for (Card lr : list) {
        String log = "ID:" + lr.getID() +" Name: " + lr.getName() + " Skill: " + lr.getSkill() + " Strength: " +lr.getStrength()
                + " Loyalty: " + lr.getLoyalty() + " Weapon: " + lr.getWeapon();
        Log.d("Database: ", log); 
    }

    Card retrieved = dh.getCard(3);
    Log.d("Database: ", "SINGLE: " + retrieved.getName());
}
```

}

Does anyone know why it won't add the other columns? Thanks for any help given.

EDIT**

I am using all the code. It is when I run the application, I get the following in the Log Cat

11-30 12:44:19.193: I/Database(364): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = table card has no column named loyalty

11-30 12:44:19.213: E/Database(364): Error inserting id=1 loyalty=33 skill=11 strength=22 weapon=44 name=Trevor

11-30 12:44:19.213: E/Database(364): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table card has no column named loyalty: , while compiling: INSERT INTO card(id, loyalty, skill, strength, weapon, name) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);

11-30 12:44:19.213: E/Database(364):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)

11-30 12:44:19.213: E/Database(364):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:91)

11-30 12:44:19.213: E/Database(364):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:64)

11-30 12:44:19.213: E/Database(364):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:80)

11-30 12:44:19.213: E/Database(364):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.(SQLiteStatement.java:36)

11-30 12:44:19.213: E/Database(364):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.compileStatement(SQLiteDatabase.java:1145)

11-30 12:44:19.213: E/Database(364):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1536)

11-30 12:44:19.213: E/Database(364):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1410)

11-30 12:44:19.213: E/Database(364):    at uk.ac.tees.L1024329.DatabaseHandler.addCard(DatabaseHandler.java:96)

11-30 12:44:19.213: E/Database(364):    at uk.ac.tees.L1024329.Browse.onCreate(Browse.java:22)

11-30 12:44:19.213: E/Database(364):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)

11-30 12:44:19.213: E/Database(364):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)

11-30 12:44:19.213: E/Database(364):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)

11-30 12:44:19.213: E/Database(364):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)

11-30 12:44:19.213: E/Database(364):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)

11-30 12:44:19.213: E/Database(364):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

11-30 12:44:19.213: E/Database(364):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)

11-30 12:44:19.213: E/Database(364):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)

11-30 12:44:19.213: E/Database(364):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

11-30 12:44:19.213: E/Database(364):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)

11-30 12:44:19.213: E/Database(364):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)

11-30 12:44:19.213: E/Database(364):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)

11-30 12:44:19.213: E/Database(364):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

EDIT*******

I have tried unistalling/ reinstalling the app and I have also tried clearing the data for the app but neither work.

Comment: `... COL_SKILL + " TEXT" + ...` where is commas after TEXT ?

Comment: I had commas in an earlier version, i've just been messing around with it so much trying to get it to work I forgot to put them in!

Comment: so next ... change `super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);` to `super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 2);` ... and increment last parameter (1, 2, 3, ...) every time you change database schema ... or delete app from device and install it again ... since without changeing this param (DATE base version) onCreate is not called again

Comment: done both these things, still nothing.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the code you're actually using. And which command fails, and what is the exact error message?

Comment: Just edited the q, please see q for error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as if you've missed out commas between the various column names. It should be

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
            + COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + COL_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + COL_SKILL + " TEXT," + 
            COL_STRENGTH + " TEXT, " 
            + COL_LOYALTY + " TEXT, " + COL_WEAPON + " TEXT"+
            ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
}
```

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE**
It's also because you haven't placed a space in between your column name variable and the column type, you would need to put a space before the word TEXT as in my amended code above.

Comment: Hi, Thank you. I have tried this but unfortunately it still doesn't work.

Comment: this is the exact root of the problem...you must perform a clean installation, because your database is corrupted now because you have already ran it with the wrong database creation script.

Comment: As has been mentioned, the oncreate will only once after the program has been installed, to make the onCreate method run again you would either need to uninstall the app from the device or clear the app data within the device settings by going to app drawer > settings > your app name > clear data

Comment: Hi I have unistalled/reinstalled and it still isn't working, also tried the clear data one as well.

Answer (score 1):

I have my fully running code.you can try modifying it as per use.

```
public class Database {

    static final String TAG="database";


    static final String DATABASE_NAME="YourDataBaseName";


    static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;


    static final String DATABASE_COLLECT_TABLE="YourTableName1";
    static final String DATABASE_FOLLOWUP_TABLE="YourTableName2";



    static final String LeadNo="LeadNo";


    static final String Name="Name";


    static final String Process="Process";


    static final String NextAptDate="NextAptDate";


    static final String Time="Time";


    static final String ChequeNo="ChequeNo";


    static final String ChequeDate="ChequeDate";


    static final String Amount="Amount";


    static final String Bank="Bank";


    static final String Status="Status";


    static final String Remarks="Remarks";


    static final String id="ID";


    static final String CREATE_COLLECT_TABLE= "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_COLLECT_TABLE + "("
            + id + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + LeadNo + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + Name + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + Process + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + ChequeNo + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + ChequeDate + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + Amount + " TEXT NOT NULL, "+ Bank + " TEXT NOT NULL, "+ Status + " TEXT NOT NULL, "+ Remarks +" TEXT NOT NULL)";

    static final String CREATE_FOLLOWUP_TABLE= "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_FOLLOWUP_TABLE + " ("
            + id + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " 
            + LeadNo + " TEXT NOT NULL, " 
            + Name + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + Process + " TEXT NOT NULL, " 
            + NextAptDate + " TEXT NOT NULL, " 
            + Time + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + Status + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + Remarks +" TEXT NOT NULL)";


    private final Context ctx;


    private DatabaseHelper dbHelper;


    private SQLiteDatabase sqlDB;


    private class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {


        public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }


        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i(TAG, "Creating Collect Database :-"+CREATE_COLLECT_TABLE);
            Log.i(TAG, "Creating FollowUp Database :-"+CREATE_FOLLOWUP_TABLE);

            db.execSQL(CREATE_COLLECT_TABLE);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_FOLLOWUP_TABLE);
        }


        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading Database from version "+ oldVersion + " to " + newVersion);
        }

    }


    public Database(Context context)
    {
        ctx=context;
    }

    public Database open() throws SQLException
    {
        dbHelper=new DatabaseHelper(ctx);
        sqlDB=dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }


    public void close()
    {
        dbHelper.close();
    }



    public long createCollect(String LeadNo,String Name,String Process,
            String ChequeNo,String ChequeDate,String Amount,
            String Bank,String Status,String Remarks)
    {
        ContentValues initialValues=new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put("LeadNo", LeadNo);
        initialValues.put("Name", Name);
        initialValues.put("Process", Process);
        initialValues.put("ChequeNo", ChequeNo);
        initialValues.put("ChequeDate", ChequeDate);
        initialValues.put("Amount", Amount);
        initialValues.put("Bank", Bank);
        initialValues.put("Status", Status);
        initialValues.put("Remarks", Remarks);

        //Checking Values
        Log.i("LeadNo", LeadNo);
        Log.i("Name", Name);
        Log.i("Process", Process);
        Log.i("ChequeNo", ChequeNo);
        Log.i("ChequeDate", ChequeDate);
        Log.i("Amount", Amount);
        Log.i("Bank", Bank);
        Log.i("Status", Status);
        Log.i("Remarks", Remarks);

        return sqlDB.insert(DATABASE_COLLECT_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }


    public long createFollowUp(String LeadNo,String Name,String Process,
            String NextAptDate,String Time,String Status,String Remarks)
    {
        ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
        values.put("LeadNo", LeadNo);
        values.put("Name", Name);
        values.put("Process", Process);
        values.put("NextAptDate", NextAptDate);
        values.put("Time", Time);
        values.put("Status", Status);
        values.put("Remarks", Remarks);

        //Checking Values
        Log.i("LeadNo", LeadNo);
        Log.i("Name", Name);
        Log.i("Process", Process);
        Log.i("NextAptDate", NextAptDate);
        Log.i("Time", Time);
        Log.i("Status", Status);
        Log.i("Remarks", Remarks);

        return sqlDB.insert(DATABASE_FOLLOWUP_TABLE, null, values);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's great that you found your solution.have a nice day ahead.

Answer (score 0):

if i understood correctly, seems that you forgot to implement the **onUpgrade()** method doing an alter table on the database to add the new columns...or if you haven't released the app yet, you can just do a clear data and try again without implementing the **onUpgrade()**...because your database was already created with the old columns set, and it won't create a new one until you  update the database version number (which will trigger the **onUpgrade()**) method call.

Comment: Hi, how would I clear the data? I am new to android development, this is the first time I have tried to create a database on a app.

Comment: you can either go to Settings/Applications/App.. and press clear data ...or simple uninstall and try it again. Note: the onUpgrade() method is only necessary if you have already released outside...so people take already have it installed can perform the update gracefully, but if the app never left your computer, just uninstall or clear data..it's easier than writing and handling the onUpgrade() scenarios.

Comment: thanks. To unistall/reinstall just be exporting and importing the app?

Comment: Hi I have unistalled/reinstalled and it still isn't working, also tried the clear data one as well.